# Sharing only dll and not source code of shared lib across 2 folders in TFS 2010

Tags: shared-libraries

I am setting up TFS for our org which comprises of 2 teams. For security purposes, we are planning to divide the code base into 3 folders, 1 for Team1, 1 for Team2 and 1 for shared libraries that are common across both the teams. An additional requirement is that both Team1 and Team2 should NOT be able to see the source code of the sharedlibraries(the sharedlibraries is itself a visual studio application) whereas they can download/getlatest the dll of the sharedlibraries

I was able to set this build up on TFS using security and groupmemberships but I am clueless about what will happen when someone from TeamB wants to getlatest and build his solution. Since he has no rights on the sharedlib, the folder wont download and he will be left with a missing reference. Any ideas on how to make this work?

Answer (score 2):

A couple if options.

1. let the developers in both teams see the code for the shared libraries (use project references)
2. Build the libraries, then check the dll's in to a subfolder of each teams work area (use binary references)
3. Build the libraries host them on a network share and use nuget to manage the dependencies (use binary references)